# Should we get the Question quality bans earlier?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

While we are still in private beta, we are trying to teach some users the ropes and trying to make their questions answerable and in good shape for the rest of the world... well, that is causing certain problems that we may need to escalate the actions when users doesn't try to follow the rules.

When we go public, I would expect a lot more of this kind of users that would go in detriment of the general quality of the site, so, maybe, we should be a bit proactive and shields up with a lazy Question Quality bans so whenever an user may not understand how things work around they get a firm nudge in the right direction.

Comment: A question ban is hardly a "firm nudge", it's more like running into a brick wall. I would be in favour of this in general but certainly not for the first few questions

Comment: @Flyk (oh god, I was so sure I commented this) remember that question quality bans are for repeater offenders and the bar is normally high for them.

Answer (score 3):

Any form of banning is for repeat, intentional offenders.
So yes, if someone is conciously ignoring the rules, or the community consensus,
a ban is appropriate.

However, under most circumstances a poor quality question should be:

- Put on hold, (Closed)
- Edited/Commented,
- Reopened

We want to be a friendly community.

When it is appropriate for a <s>mod</s> the system to impose a question asking ban,
it will be (/Must be) really obvious, to the <s>mod</s> highly sophisicated algorithms of the system.
 (But not nesc to anyone who hasn't been really following what is going on).

**Edit:**
as was said in comments mods can't impost question bans.
However SE has really good algorithms for recognising people being terrible.
I have some issues with the lack of human touch, but it is better than being heavy handed.

Comment: Mods aren't able to impose Questions bans.